# Set state from a child component: getting either an infinite loop or a warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set state on a parent component from one of its children that runs a timer function with `useEffect`. I've passed a handler from the parent to the child using props and I'm calling it from the child when some condition is met.

Setting the state in the parent created an infinite loop, presumably because setting the state on the parent re-rendered the parent and redefined a new function every time, I'm not sure. Anyway, I resolved it with `useCallback`, as in this simplified example:

```js
const MIDNIGHT = Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const handleChangeState = useCallback((value) => {
    setState(value)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Child onUpdate={handleChangeState} />
      <p>{state}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = ({ onUpdate }) => {
  const [now, setNow] = useState()

  // Run a timer
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setNow(Date.now())
    }, 100)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  })

  const msElapsed = now - MIDNIGHT
  const someOtherValue = msElapsed * 1
  // ...plus several other calculations.
  // The value assigned to "someOtherValue" is different
  // every few seconds but needs to be checked frequently

  useEffect(() => {
    if (someOtherValue) {
      onUpdate(someOtherValue)
    }
  }, [someOtherValue, onUpdate])

  return (
    <p>{someOtherValue}</p>
  )
}
```

This was working as I intended. However, now I need to set another state on the parent, like this:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState()
  const [anArray, setAnArray] = useState([])

  const handleChangeState = useCallback((value) => {
    setState(value)
    setAnArray([...anArray, value])
  }, [anArray])

  return (
    <Child onUpdate={handleChangeState} />
  )
}
```

This causes an infinite loop because every time `setArray` is called the `useCallback` dependency value changes and triggers a new render which then triggers the handler function again.

So, I figured, I'll dump the `useCallback` and `useEffect`, rely on "just calculating what the user needs to see" and manually trigger the handler by comparing the `someOtherValue` to a stored `ref`, like this:

```js
const lastValue = useRef(0)
if (someOtherValue !== lastValue.current) { 
    lastValue.current = someOtherValue
    handleChangeState(someOtherValue)
}
```

But now I get "Cannot update a component (`Parent`) while rendering a different component (`Child`)".

How is this behavior supposed to be designed in React?

EDIT: I managed to get the intended behavior by combining *both* `useRef` and `useEffect`, by nesting the manual reference comparison inside the `useEffect` hook. But I'm essentially reacting twice to a change in `someOtherValue`: first as a dependency of `useEffect`, and
then with the `if` statement comparing its value to the last ref value. Isn't there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this? How?

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleChangeState` method in the Parent component does not need to be wrapped in `useCallback`; You can just directly call `setState` instead, because the `useState` hook is already memoized.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If I remove the `useCallback` wrapper and keep `useEffect` in the child, I get an infinite loop. If instead, in the child, I use the `useRef` comparison method, I get the "Cannot update" error I described in my question.